# Attach knockout in parent file and use it in iframe

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, parent-child

My application is based on knockout and the big hurdle for me is as follows:

1. I've attached required JS files in main parent file
2. I've used an approach to refer to these files in iFrame. For example jQuery defined only in parent and just refer to it from iframe defining it's object in iframe.
3. Similarly I am able to define knockout object and use it but, THE ISSUE is that - bindings on the iframe page is not working
4. If i use alert to check if the functions of knockout works or not, it is working. Only the form fields and data-bindings are not working

Any clue?

Here is the code:
Parent file (under head):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
```

(under body)

```
<iframe src="IframePage.html" width="100%" height="100%" id="popUpIframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Iframe File:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    var $ = parent.$;
    var ko = parent.ko;    
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var ViewModel = function (first, last) {
            this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
            this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

            this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
                alert(this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName());
                return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
            }, this);
        };        
         ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Kawal", "Babra"));
    });
</script>
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply specify the root element to be an element within the iframes' document, eg:

`ko.applyBindings(Model, document.body)`;

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rD8uR/

Here's the iframe document: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KkPdE/show/light/

Comment: Thanks Buddy, It helped me alot. Worked after tweaking the settings. Well, the line var $ = parent.$; is not working as it seems like jquery is not being imported.